# why am I getting long long maximum value as a return value?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, outputstream

I am trying to output -1 when the two strings are equal , but instead I get the unsigned long long maximum value as a return value , I tried casting -1 to long long and unsigned long long but it's not working , It worked when I used if-else condition and it also worked when I stored the return value of the expression in a variable , but why is it not working when I'm outputting the return value directly ?

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::string a,b;
    std::cin>>a>>b;
    std::cout<<(a!=b?std::max(a.length(),b.length()):-1);
}
```

Comment: Muhamed: Did the answer help to clear things up? If anything is unclear, please ask and I'll try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`std::max(a.length(),b.length())` has an *unsigned* type (incapable of holding negative values). `std::size_t`. `-1` will be converted to the same type and `std::size_t(-1)` becomes the largest value a `std::size_t` can hold.

To work around the problem, you can cast `std::max(a.length(), b.length())` to a *signed* type, like `std::intmax_t`:

Example:

```
#include <cstdint>

std::cout<<(a != b ? static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::max(a.length(), b.length())) : -1);
```